# How to find memory usage of oracle in unix?

Tags: unix, oracle11g, aix, database-administration

I have been searching this for a while, but dint get a solution(Might be i'm not doing it proper). My problem is to find the memory that is getting utilized by oracle in AIX unix. I had installed Oracle 11gr2 and running multiple db instances. I'm able to get the PID of the SID for which i'm trying find the memory utilization, but not able to figure out the approximate memory that it is using. Please help me with this.

Comment: `man top`? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
ps v <pid>
```

do what you want?  ps has tons of options to get various attributes of a process.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with "top" ... it should list the currently running processes with some statistics on their processor and memory usage.